# Stored Procedure - Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert a float value from one table into another, but am getting the error in the subject line of this post:

Error converting data type varchar to float.

Both fields in both tables are set to float.  Values are latitudes and longitudes for zip codes.  An example of a latitude/longitude would be:

45.895698
-72.365896

Here is a few snippets of my code:

```
declare @v_latitude float
declare @v_longitude float

-- Grab Latitude & Longitude --
if @v_zip_code IS NOT NULL
SELECT @v_latitude=z_latitude, @v_longitude=z_longitude FROM tbl_ZipCodes WHERE z_zip_code = @v_zip_code

set @strValues = @strValues + '''' + @v_city + ''', ''' + @v_state + ''', ''' + @v_zip_code + ''', ''' + @v_daytime_phone + ''', ''' + @v_contact_name + ''', '''
+ @v_email_address + ''', '  + cast(@u_id as varchar) + ', ' +  cast(@d_id as varchar) + ', 1, ''' + cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar) + ''', 1 , ''' + cast(@v_latitude as float) + ''', ''' + cast(@v_longitude as float) + ''', '''
+ cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar) + ''', dft.df_t_id, (SELECT CASE WHEN dft.df_t_v_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_price WHEN dft.df_t_v_internet_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_internet_price WHEN dft.df_t_v_other_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_other_price ELSE 0 END AS v_search_price)'
```

The part of the code that uses the @v_latitude and @v_longitude variables is here:

```
... , ''' + cast(@v_latitude as float) + ''', ''' + cast(@v_longitude as float) + ''', ...
```

Ignore the "..." as I am demonstrating there is additional code that surrounds those values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here is additional code I am using:

```
-- Check For User Profile --
SELECT @counter = COUNT(*) FROM tbl_Customers WHERE u_id = @u_id
if @counter > 0
    SELECT @v_city=c_city, @v_state =c_state, @v_zip_code=c_zip_code,@v_daytime_phone =c_phone_number FROM tbl_Customers WHERE u_id = @u_id
else
    SELECT @v_city=d_city, @v_state =d_state, @v_zip_code=d_zip_code,@v_daytime_phone =d_phone_number FROM tbl_Dealers WHERE d_id = @d_id

-- Grab Contact Information --
SELECT @v_contact_name = u_name, @v_email_address = u_email_address FROM tbl_Users WHERE u_id = @u_id


-- Grab Latitude & Longitude --
if @v_zip_code IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @v_latitude=z_latitude, @v_longitude=z_longitude FROM tbl_ZipCodes WHERE z_zip_code = @v_zip_code


-- Add Additional Fields --
set @strFields = @strFields + 'v_city, v_state, v_zip_code, v_daytime_phone, v_contact_name, v_email_address, u_id, d_id, v_processed, v_processed_date, v_active, ,v_latitude, v_longitude, v_last_activity, v_dealerfeed, v_search_price'
set @strJoin = @strJoin + ' LEFT JOIN tbl_Vehicles v ON v.v_stock_number = dft.df_t_v_stock_number'
set @strValues = @strValues + '''' + @v_city + ''', ''' + @v_state + ''', ''' + @v_zip_code + ''', ''' + @v_daytime_phone + ''', ''' + @v_contact_name + ''', '''
 + @v_email_address + ''', '  + cast(@u_id as varchar) + ', ' +  cast(@d_id as varchar) + ', 1, ''' + cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar) + ''', 1 , ''' + @v_latitude + ''', ''' + @v_longitude + ''', '''
 + cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar) + ''', dft.df_t_id, (SELECT CASE WHEN dft.df_t_v_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_price WHEN dft.df_t_v_internet_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_internet_price WHEN dft.df_t_v_other_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_other_price ELSE 0 END AS v_search_price)'

-- Insert Records Into Vehicle Table (but not twice!) --
set @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO tbl_Vehicles (' + @strFields + ') SELECT ' + @strValues + ' FROM tbl_DealerFeed_temp dft ' + @strJoin + ' WHERE dft.df_t_processed = 0 AND dft.df_d_id = ' +  cast(@df_d_id as varchar)
set @strSQL =  @strSQL + ' AND dft.df_t_v_stock_number NOT IN ( SELECT v.v_stock_number FROM tbl_Vehicles v WHERE v.d_id = ' + cast(@d_id as varchar) + ')'

print @strSQL

EXEC (@strSQL)
```

Comment: If it's already a float, and you are trying to concatenate it to a string, you need to convery the float to a (n)varchar

Comment: @Jeremy - I am not sure I understand what you are saying.  I understand it is already declared as a float.  When I try the following, I get the same error as I originally stated `-- ''' + @v_latitude + ''', ''' + @v_longitude + '''`

Comment: I think you need to post more of the code around the error.  It looks like you are trying to build a string and are trying to concatenate float-type variables into the string, which is not allowed.

Comment: Additional code added to bottom of original post.

Comment: why are you trying to do this with dynamic sql?

Comment: This is a dealer feed and every dealer feed is different.  I am required to read the setup for each dealer feed and create a SQL string to load each dealers vehicles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably is the fact that your dynamic sql is putting single quotes around the float.

Try changing

```
 , ''' + cast(@v_latitude as float) + ''', ''' + cast(@v_longitude as float) + ''', ..
```

into

```
 , ' + STR(@v_latitude,<length>,<decimals>) + ', ' + STR(@v_longitude,<length>,<decimals>) + ', ..
```

See [STR ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) for reference

Comment: Tom, currently my code is cutting off decimal places.  I am using the code suggested below `CONVERT(varchar(20), @v_latitude)`.  Will your code alleviate this issue?

Comment: No, i had the reply window open for a while so Hugo typed his response while i was away. I should've refreshed the page first. Our code does about the same. I'll update my answer

Comment: Except that `STR` on it's own will round the Float to no decimal places. Do `STR(@v_latitude,18,9)`

Comment: Added placeholders in the answer for completeness

Answer (score 1):

As you're doing dynamic SQL you force everything down to a string type.

But it's the single quotes that are tripping you up. If the column you're inserting into is a float you don't want your float value on the insert wrapped in quotes.

Also I find `CONVERT` is a little more flexible (with dates mostly) than `CAST` (I've only done CONVERT for diversity):

so you want get rid of those triple quotes:

`...+ CONVERT(varchar(20), @v_latitude) +',' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @v_longitude) +...`

Edited to add: your fixed code should look like this:

```
set @strValues = @strValues + '''' + @v_city + ''', ''' + @v_state + ''', ''' + @v_zip_code + ''', ''' + @v_daytime_phone + ''', ''' + @v_contact_name + ''', '''
 + @v_email_address + ''', '  + cast(@u_id as varchar) + ', ' +  cast(@d_id as varchar) + ', 1, ''' + cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar) + ''', 1 , ' + Convert(varchar(20), @v_latitude) + ', ' + Convert(varchar(20), @v_longitude) + ', '''
 + cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar) + ''', dft.df_t_id, (SELECT CASE WHEN dft.df_t_v_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_price WHEN dft.df_t_v_internet_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_internet_price WHEN dft.df_t_v_other_price <> 0 THEN dft.df_t_v_other_price ELSE 0 END AS v_search_price)'
```

Execute your SQL *without* the `EXEC (@strSQL)` and have a look at the printed SQL

**Edited again**;  to fix your Float being limited to being rounded to 4 decimal places (this is down to it being a Float) but you can get around it by converting it to a decimal first or using `STR`, this'll help you understand what's happening:

```
declare @v_latitude float = -45.12345678
print @v_latitude
print 'Cast = '+ cast( @v_latitude as varchar)
print 'Convert = '+ convert(varchar(20), @v_latitude)
print 'Cast via decimal = '+ cast( cast(@v_latitude as decimal(18,9)) as varchar)
print 'Convert via decimal = '+ convert( varchar(20), convert(decimal(18,9), @v_latitude))
print 'str = '+ str(@v_latitude,18,9)

==
-45.1235
Cast = -45.1235
Convert = -45.1235
Cast via decimal = -45.123456780
Convert via decimal = -45.123456780
str =  -45.123456780
```

Comment: I got the following error:  Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'

Comment: That seemed to do the trick.  However, it is cutting off part of the decimal value.  For instance, value 45.751671 is being entered into the DB as 45.7517.  Do I just need to increase the varchar(20) size?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
 ''' + cast( @v_latitude  as varchar(20))
 + ''', ''' + cast((@v_longitude as varchar(20))+ '''
```

Comment: Variables can be either a float or a string. If you want to store it in a column of type float you want it to be of type float it if you want it to be part of a string it must be a string (char or nchar) or cast it to become a string.